# Codechef problem Given integers N and M, find the number of ordered pairs (a,b) such that 1≤a<b≤N and ((M mod a) mod b) = ((M mod b) mod a) help plss

Tags: python, algorithm, modular-arithmetic

this is so far all i have done
i am trying to optimize the code for less time.but it is not working.

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
n, m = map(int, input().split())
count = 0
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        if i < j <= n and ((m%i)%j) == ((m%j)%i):
            count += 1
print(count)
```

another approach I tried:

```py
if i < j <= n and (m-(m%j))%i == 0:
```

both condition give correct result.but show time limit exceed

what should i do.thanks

Comment: Could you link the problem

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/MAY21C/problems/MODEQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is a good start but takes exactly `N * N` iterations.

You can start with following improvements.

1. sort the data
2. Using 2 pointer approach with optimised search range for second pointer

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(i+1, n+1): # note j start at `i+1`
```

Comment: it works and time is also below 1 sec.but it is partially accepted.all sub task is not fullfilled.by the way,thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Since a < b, we infer that (M mod a) mod b = M mod a, so the condition is equivalent to M mod a = (M mod b) mod a, i.e., M − (M mod b) is a multiple of a. We can iterate over all b and count factors of M − (M mod b) using a sieve, resulting in a Θ(N + M log N)-time algorithm.

```
N = 2304
M = 23498


def fast():
    npairs = 0
    nfactors = [1] * (M + 1)
    for b in range(2, N + 1):
        npairs += nfactors[M - M % b]
        for i in range(0, M + 1, b):
            nfactors[i] += 1
    return npairs


def naive():
    return sum((M % a) % b == (M % b) % a for b in range(2, N + 1) for a in range(1, b))


print(fast(), naive())
```

Comment: thanks. that's very useful.i solve it.u guys are awesome

Comment: How is the runtime theta(N + M log N) here? , shouldnt it be O(N*logM)?

Comment: @RohitSarkar no, if M is much larger than N, we exceed that time bound as soon as we construct `nfactors`.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like x%mod(a) is same as x%mod(b) only condition a<b and if mod(b) is calculated, don't need to calculate mod(a) again if its already stored .

(n-1) is for all the pairs of 1's

```
for _ in range(int(input())):

    n,m=map(int,input().split())

    count=0

    dictitems=defaultdict(int)

    for i in range(2,n+1):

        rem=m%i

        count+=dictitems[rem]

        for j in range(rem,n+1,i):

            dictitems[j]+=1

    print(count+(n-1))
```